# SELECT from multiple tables and display in a table

Tags: jquery, mysql, listbox

I have two tables called `order` and `order_items`

```
order_id--pupil_id --date_bought--total_price

1  ----1001---- 2013-03-07 23:35:49 - 1.00
```

and

```
order_id-- product_name

1 ------ product1

1 ------ product2
```

I want to display date bought and total price. It will be some sort of join statement with the products that have been bought with the most recent order_id which would be order by desc maybe in the statement

I'm unsure on how to piece it together. Any ideas or clues on how to achieve this?

Comment: Post the query you have tried and the problem you are facing

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT product_name, date_bought, total_price
FROM `order` o
JOIN `order_items` oi
ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
ORDER BY o.order_id DESC
```

Comment: i forgot to add

i need the approriate row selected by pupil id.

so where pupil_id = $id, where would this go?

Comment: WHERE o.pupil_id = $id would go between the ON and ORDER BY lines (assuming you inject $id in).

Comment: thanks, ive made some progress

i have made this now

$query = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM `order` o
JOIN `order_items` oi
ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
ORDER BY o.order_id DESC");

$query_assoc = mysql_fetch_array($query);

echo $query_assoc['product_name'];
echo $query_assoc['date_bought'];
echo $query_assoc['total_price'];

how do i retrieve all rows associated with that pupil id in descending order of order id? thanks

Comment: You'd need to put in the WHERE clauses and then loop through the rows using a syntax like while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { ... }

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    od.date_bought, 
    od.total price, 
    group_concat(odi.product_name separator ', ') 
FROM order, order_items 
WHERE 
    order.order_id od = order_items.order_id odi 
GROUP BY odi.order_id
ORDER BY od.order_id DESC;
```